# Create a dataframe from MultiLCA results in Brightway2

Tags: pandas, brightway

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from the results of a MultiLCA calculation, using as columns the methods and as rows the functional units. I did find a sort of solution, but it is a bit cumbersome (I am not very good with dictionaries)

```
...
mlca=MultiLCA("my_calculation_setup")
pd.DataFrame(mlca.results,columns=mlca.methods)

fu_names=[]

for d in mlca.func_units:
    for key in d:
        fu_names.append(str(key))

dfresults['fu']=fu_names
dfresults.set_index('fu',inplace=True)
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this? The names are also very long, but that's a different story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems relatively elegant to me. If you want to stick with `str(key)`, then you could simplify it somewhat with a list comprehension:

```
mlca=MultiLCA("my_calculation_setup")
dfresults = pd.DataFrame(mlca.results, columns=mlca.methods)

dfresults['fu'] = [str(key) for demand in mlca.func_units for key in demand]
dfresults.set_index('fu', inplace=True)
```

Note that this only works if your demand dictionaries have one activity each. You could have situations where one demand dictionary would have two activities (like `LCA({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})`), where this would fail because there would be too many elements in the `fu` list.

If you do know that you only have one activity per demand, then you can make a slightly nicer dataframe as follows:

```
mlca=MultiLCA("my_calculation_setup")
scores = pd.DataFrame(mlca.results, columns=mlca.methods)

as_activities = [
    (get_activity(key), amount) 
    for dct in mlca.func_units 
    for key, amount in dct.items()
]
nicer_fu = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (x['database'], x['code'], x['name'], x['location'], x['unit'], y) 
        for x, y in as_activities
    ], 
    columns=('Database', 'Code', 'Name', 'Location', 'Unit', 'Amount')
)
nicer = pd.concat([nicer_fu, scores], axis=1)
```

However, in the general case dataframes as not a perfect match for calculation setups. When a demand dictionary has multiple activities, there is no nice way to "squish" this into one dimension or one row.